# oAuth2 RestClient Get token not working even though Postman works

Tags: c#, rest-client

Below are the parameters required to get a successful token in Postman.

Token Name: Sage Access Token

Grant Type: Authorization Code

Callback URL: https://dummyaddress

Authorize using browser: Unticked

Auth URL: https://dummyaddress

Access Token URL: https://id.sage.com/oauth/token

Client ID: your client ID

Client Secret: your client secret

Scope: openid profile email offline_access

Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth header

When I try via code I get UnAuthorized.

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://id.sage.com/oauth/token");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //  request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=Authorization_Code&client_id=DxpXMEWXW1oVjn5l4DwRuw9d0bRzpUlG&client_secret=MlUMsZINFBovHODAjmtfG8rO8kjVyiaDYgvfyeg1lmaMArC2ihyd1jh-5u2GyqU&Scope=openid profile email offline_access&Callback_URL=https://customerdataquestuk--sage--c.visualforce.com/apex/SageCode &Auth_URL=https://id.sage.com/authorize?audience=s200ukipd/sage200", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.AddParameter("Grant_Type", "Authorization Code");
        request.AddParameter("Callback_URL", "https://dummyaddress");
        request.AddParameter("Auth_URL", "https://dummyaddress");
        request.AddParameter("Client_ID", your client ID);
        request.AddParameter("Client_Secret", your client secret);
        request.AddParameter("Scope", "openid profile email offline_access");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Auth header is missing in your code, You can manually create a basic authentication header using the following C# code:

```
var credentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", clientId, clientSecret);
var headerValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials));

var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", headerValue);
```

or if you RestClient

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(clientId,clientSecret);
```

please check this document  [Client Authentication](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/client_authentication.html)